# Can the 2019 UA Artificer's Returning Weapon and Radiant Weapon infusions stack on the same weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, unearthed-arcana, stacking, artificer

Can the [2019 UA Artificer](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-Artificer2-2019.pdf)'s Returning Weapon and Radiant Weapon infusions stack on the same weapon?

Each infusion grants you a +1 to hit and damage rolls, so would you get a +2 with both infusions?

My thought is that you can only infuse one weapon at a time.

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. Since there are several versions of the Artificer published in UA, can you confirm which one you are asking about?

Comment: I assume you're asking about the most recent UA from May 2019?

Answer (score 21):

#### No, they don't.

You can infuse only nonmagical items and an infusion turns an item magical. From page 5 of [the Artificer Returns document](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-Artificer2-2019.pdf):

> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch a nonmagical object and imbue it with one of your artificer infusions, turning it into a magic item.

Answer (score 8):

> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch a nonmagical object and
>   imbue it with one of your artificer infusions, turning it into a magic
>   item.

After you apply the first imbue to it, it is a magical item.  That makes it not a nonmagical object, and therefore nto a valid target for infusion.  They do not stack.